# How to get time difference in VBScript

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, vbscript

I have VB Script which is connected with the my database (SQL Server 2008), and this script query contains `getdate()` function, now I want to subtract 2 time value suppose SQL1-SQL2 and want only time difference, not the date.

Comment: MySQL 2008 != MS SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, SQL2, SQL1) FROM dbo.table;
```

If you want to do it in VBScript, then something like:

```vb
x = datediff("n", rs("SQL2"), rs("SQL1"))
```

[T-SQL docs for datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
[VBScript docs for datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhtyw595%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)